# Modal Bottom sheet draggable ListView and fixed title not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Im trying to achieve a modal bottom sheet with a top fixed title and a scrollview below it.

```dart
showModalBottomSHeet(context: context, isScrollControlled: true, builder (_) => Column(
  children: [
    Text(...),
    Expanded(child: ListView(children: ...))
  ]
));
```

My issue is when I use the Column the sheet doesnt get dragged when I drag in the ListView beyond its top edge, the ListView just bounces and the bottom sheet hasnt moved.

If I remove the Column and place the title as first child of ListView then the sheet gets dragged but then of course my title isnt fixed at the top anymore.

Any ideas?

## SOLVED

I wrapped my Column in:

```dart
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: 1,
  minChildSize: 0.5,
  expand: false,
  snap: true,
```

Comment: Are you using `DraggableScrollableSheet` ?

Comment: Thank you I solved it with DraggableScrollableSheet!